# Constraint to force pair of IDs

Tags: mysql, index, constraint

I would like a constraint to force a pair of IDs.

For example, I have a table with two columns.

1. car_id
2. tire_id

However, a specific `car_id` must always be paired with the same `tired_id`.  Meaning a car can only have one specific tire.

| car_id | tire_id | other_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 8 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 8 | 6 |
| 1 | 9 | 7 |

In the above example, all values are acceptable, except `(1, 9)`, because a `car_id` of `1` is already paired with a `tire_id`.

I also added the `other_id` just to show that this table contains other IDs that are not relevant to the constraint I want.

Also, both `car_id` and `tire_id` have FKs to their respective tables.

Note, I am specifically using MySQL, but I'm curious if there's a specific solution for other flavors of SQL.

**EDIT**

The more I think about this problem the more I realize that the `tire` table should instead be related to the `car` table and this table should only be related to the `car` table, but assuming I can't change the table structure, is there a different solution for what I'm looking for?

Comment: *In the example above all values are acceptable except (1, 9) because a car_id of 1 is already paired with a tire_id.* Why? Maybe the row (1,9) is correct whereas both rows (1,1) are wrong?

Comment: In MySQL this constraint can be implemented in the trigger.

Comment: @Akina it's assumed that the first inserted value is the correct value.

Comment: @Akina can you post an answer with an example?

Comment: Based on the examples you're provided, I'm wondering if you're choosing the right solution for the problem. Can you provide the full schema of the table in question? Will cars also be stored in other tables? I would think a more appropriate approach would be a table that stores one row per car_id, along with it's appropriate tire_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_cars_custom_constraint
BEFORE INSERT ON cars
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM cars
                WHERE car_id = NEW.car_id AND tire_id <> NEW.tire_id ) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Another tire is registered for this car already!';
    END IF;
END
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d6e12631e2bdeb1f424800d1527a6d0)

Pay attention - if the query inserts more than one rows and at least one of them contains incorrect value then the qhole query will fail and none rows will be inserted.

Comment: Does this work if two concurrent transactions insert the same values?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This everything (including the trigger) is one INSERT query which is a transaction. So the answer does this can cause problems in concurrent environ depends on current default transaction level.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote "*but I'm curious if there's a specific solution for other flavours of SQL*"

This would be possible in Postgres using an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION)

```
alter table tires
  add constraint single_tire 
  exclude using gist (car_id with =, tire_id with <>);
```

So the first combination of `(car_id, tire_id)` will then constrain all subsequent ones. If there is a row with `(1,1,x)`, inserting another row with `(1,1,y)` will work, but inserting `(1,2,y)` will not.

Answer (score 1):

The schema needs changing.

The table `Cars` should have `PRIMARY KEY(car_id)` and another column with `tire_id`, plus other attributes of the car.

The table `Tires` should have `PRIMARY KEY(tire_id)` plus any attributes of that tire type.

There should be no other table with *both* `car_id` and `tire_id`.

Comment: You're right, if I had the opportunity to change the tables then I would've accepted this as the correct answer. I accepted the other answer because I don't have the opportunity to change the tables atm. Thank you